# Custom routing and get ids from url

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a model name "profit" and it has a table name profits and 3 column of the table "price", "sell", "grossprofit"

Now in my index.html.erb page I have option for show as

```
<td><%= link_to 'Show', profit %></td>
```

when I click on the show link i go to show page and link become

```
http://localhost:3000/students/1
http://localhost:3000/students/2
```

that is i am getting id of profits table but I need price and sell in my url like below

```
http://localhost:3000/students/3/5
```

where 3 will be sell and 5 will be price

What changes I have to do to get this url and how can I get price and sell from the url in show action of the controller?

Answer (score 0):

create route like this in routes.rb. put this before resources :students

```
get '/students/:sell/:price, to: "students#show"
```

now run rake routes and see what helper it will create and use that

Comment: can you paste your config/routes.rb content and the output of rake routes command